# How do I make this directory public with nginx?<

Tags: nginx, ghost-blog

I have a ghost.org pre-built droplet on DigitalOcean that I'm willing to use for a music production blog. This is what my site conf looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root; # Used for acme.sh SSL verification (https://acme.sh)

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2369;

    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

I want to serve some html pages I uploaded at this directory /var/www/downloads when people visits my domain.com/downloads. How do I do it leaving everything else working? I've tried this

```
location /downloads/ {
    alias /var/www/downloads/;
}
```

but it did not work. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location /downloads {
    root /var/www;
}
```